# How to disabled Jump of the thirdpersoncontroller - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog, unity3d-unet

I have a problem , I make a dialogue text in unity using c#. Well I need know how disabled jump of thirdpersoncontroller (default player of unity), because is not see good .

Like this :

[image]

This is the code :

```html
 

        private void Update()
        {
  if (!m_Jump) {
   m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Jump");
   
  
  } 
        }


        // Fixed update is called in sync with physics
        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            // read inputs
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
            bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

            // calculate move direction to pass to character
            if (m_Cam != null)
            {
                // calculate camera relative direction to move:
                m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
                m_Move = v*m_CamForward + h*m_Cam.right;
            }
            else
            {
                // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
                m_Move = v*Vector3.forward + h*Vector3.right;
            }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
   // walk speed multiplier
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

            // pass all parameters to the character control script
            m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
            m_Jump = false;
        }
    }
```

I try

Please Help me I don't know how fix it.

Thanks!!

Comment: The code will be in one of the classes placed on the gameobject. What have you tried already?

Comment: @Bejasc I update the post for you see

Comment: I've provided you with an answer, but this is really quite a basic issue. Did you read this code at all? Before posting questions here, you should make an effort and an attempt yourself to fix the issue, and post here detailing what you _have_ tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable jumping, remove the code that triggers it.

This line in `Update()` is what triggers a player to jump.

```
m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Jump");
```

Comment: Nice thanks , but I need some like this m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown (""); but not working ,  for disabled all keys of keyboard , m_Jump = ("Jump") is for active again but for disable the key ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. To remove the Jump feature (as you asked) you just need to remove that line. You have to provide something in `GetButtonDown()` - if you don't want to register the button press, why would you code `GetButtonDown()` at all??